# AutoMapper Projections are not applied

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, projection

I'm trying to make a framework to abstract my Entity Layers,  However for this to work I need automapper projects to work so I can Query my DTO's instead of Querying the Entities

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Verify_Mapping_Projection_Behavior()
{
    var projectionModifier = "Alabastar";
    var services = this.GetRegisteredRestEzServiceCollection();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var context = (AstootContext)serviceProvider.GetService<DbContext>();

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>().ForMember(x => x.FirstName, 
            o => o.MapFrom((entity, dto) => entity.FirstName + projectionModifier));
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    // Hack: we'll verify exeuction happens in sql
    // using the behavioral differene between in memory and sql (case insensitivity)
    var sqlOnlyModifier = projectionModifier.ToUpper();
    var userDTO = mapper.ProjectTo<UserDTO>(context.Users)
        .Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(sqlOnlyModifier))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.IsNotNull(userDTO);
}
```

My test failed, so I decided to materialize the projection directly. When I materialize I can see that my  `projectionModifier` is not being added to the firstName property.

How can I get the project to map my modifier, so that I can use my DTO's as Sql Queryables?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu,  I've read the documentation, my projects aren't being applied at all, not just in sql, they don't even occur in memory.

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea. In SQL it might crash and runtime, but that's smth else.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, if SQL crashes at run time shouldn't it not return data, when I call to list it still materializes fine

Comment: Surely you can find some working examples and find out exactly what you're doing wrong. For example https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/master/src/IntegrationTests.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks, for the integration tests, It solved my issue

Comment: I think the 3 parameter overload requires assignment

Answer (score 1):

The 3 parameter overload for MapFrom requires assignment. This can be resolved by using the 2 parameter overload.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.FirstName, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.FirstName + projectionModifier));
});
```